# interfacing problems with TC74A5 on STM32F411VET using I2C

Tags: c, sensors, i2c, stm32f4discovery, interfacing

trying to read data from a temperature sensor TC74A5 using I2C Bus isnt working for me. 0 is being constantly shown on my 7-Segment Display.

```
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
const uint8_t Sensor_Address = (0x4D << 1); //left-shift 7-Bit slave address of the sensor to allow space for W/R-Bit as 8th Bit
const uint8_t TEMP_Reg = 0x00; //temperature register address
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  uint8_t buf;
  uint8_t temp_data = 0;
  float temp_value_celsius = 0.0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  Reset_7Seg();

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      buf= TEMP_Reg;

//    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
//    {
//        // Initialization Error
//        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5);
//        HAL_Delay(500);
//    }
//
////       Wait for the I2C peripheral to become ready
//    while (HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) != HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
//    {
//    }

      // Send a start condition on the I2C bus
      if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, Sensor_Address, &buf, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
      {
          // Transmitting Error
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_9);
          HAL_Delay(250);
      }

      // Send a repeated start condition on the I2C bus to initiate a read operation of 1 byte from the TC74A5 sensor
      if (HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, Sensor_Address | 0x01, &temp_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK) //1 for reading data
      {
          // Receiving Error
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_8);
          HAL_Delay(250);
      }
//
//    // Disable the I2C peripheral
//    HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c1);

      // Convert the temperature data to float
      temp_value_celsius = (float)temp_data;
      temp_value_celsius *= 10;

      Write_7Seg(temp_value_celsius, 2);
      HAL_Delay(500);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 100;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PE3 PE8 PE9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA6 PA7 PA8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC5 PC9 PC10 PC11
                           PC12 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD0 PD6 PD7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

I started the communication on the I2C bus by using the HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit and prompt the sensor to send data using HAL_I2C_Master_Receive for the reply of the sensor. The LEDs connected to port E9 (GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_9) and E8 (GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_8) conctantly blinks. leading me to believe that there is an error with the communication.

The Function Write_7Seg() is working and was checkd using a different programm.

Comment: If the LEDs are blinking, then the HAL functions are failing. What are the return values from the HAL functions?

Comment: I added a function HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady() before the Master_Transmit function and got the return value HAL_BUSY. this is also the same return value, that I read from the Master_Transmit and Master_Receive functions. I checked the return values by just changing the parameter of the if-Instruction with HAL_OK, HAL_BUSY or HAL_ERROR.

Comment: The problem has been fixed, i forgot to enable the pullup resistors for the I2C pins in the CubeIDE. Also there was a minor mistake with my code